# how to get value form joinAttribute from eav_attribute_option_value table?

Tags: custom-options, customer-grid

i installed a plugin for add customer fields.
after that i have added a field name "status" to customer form.
and status field is dropdown.
now i want to display that in customer grid.
for that i have added

```
->joinAttribute('status', 'customer/status', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
```

in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php

in _prepareCollection() so collection is now $collection =

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->joinAttribute('status', 'customer/status', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
```

and also added in _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('status', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('customer status'),
    'index'     => 'status',
));
```

it's display option_id. but i want to display option value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Make your column look like this:

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'status');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

$this->addColumn('status', array(
    'type'      => 'options',
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('customer status'),
    'index'     => 'status',
    'options'   => $options
));
```

Comment: Thanks Marius,
i have added code but "customer status" column is blank now. and i have also check $options it's get proper value.

Comment: I've updated the answer. try with `'options' => $options ` instead of `'values' => $options `

Comment: still it's blank column